# Query won't run on localhost

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I have this query which is pulling data from a master table in the master DB and a a user DB using joins.

```
SELECT 
  `user_details`.`id` AS `masterid`, 
  `user_details`.`emailaddress`,
  `user_details`.`is_login` as `userstate`, 
  `user_details`.`fullname` as fullname, 
  `user_details`.`securitytemplate`, 
  `user_details`.`registered`, 
  `user_details`.`isactive`, 
  `users`.`id` AS `userid`,
  `users`.`profilepicture` AS `userpic`,
  security.templatename 
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM `gs_master`.`user_details` 
  WHERE `gs_master`.`user_details`.`db_identifier`= 136) AS `user_details` 
  LEFT JOIN gs_db_136.`users` 
    ON `user_details`.`emailaddress` = `users`.`email` 
  JOIN gs_db_136.`security_templates` AS security 
    ON security.id = `gs_master`.`user_details`.securitytemplate 
ORDER BY 
  fullname ASC
```

Strange thing is it runs on my Centos box, but wont run on my localhost.  I have updated the databases and the tables all exist.  If I query on the localhost table directly I get a result, so I am not really sure what it might be?  I am guessing it must be something to do with the allowed syntax on the different machines?

Error I get is:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'gs_master.user_details.securitytemplate' in 'on clause'

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: simply you miss the column `securitytemplate` in the table `user_details` verify and fix it. You should remove the database selection part `gs_master.'  if you are running the query there

Comment: `gs_master` & `user_details` are two table, you have to specify from which table you are taking the column `securitytemplate`

Comment: Use the qub-query alias instead, i.e.  `user_details`.securitytemplate.

Comment: gs_master is the database and user_details is the table in the database and security_template is the column in that table.  it is defintely there, I can write a short query to pull results from that table and column directly.  Keep in mind I am saying this query works on my Centos live server.  Just not onmy localhosts, even though I just went and copies both databases to make sure they are up to date.

Comment: FYI, thanks for the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are try to get:

```
SELECT 
  `user_details`.`id` AS `masterid`, 
  `user_details`.`emailaddress`,
  `user_details`.`is_login` as `userstate`, 
  `user_details`.`fullname` as fullname, 
  `user_details`.`securitytemplate`, 
  `user_details`.`registered`, 
  `user_details`.`isactive`, 
  `users`.`id` AS `userid`,
  `users`.`profilepicture` AS `userpic`,
  security.templatename 
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM `gs_master`.`user_details` 
  WHERE `gs_master`.`user_details`.`db_identifier`= 136) AS `user_details` 
  LEFT JOIN gs_db_136.`users` 
    ON `user_details`.`emailaddress` = `users`.`email` 
  JOIN gs_db_136.`security_templates` AS security 
    ON security.id = `user_details`.securitytemplate 
ORDER BY 
  fullname ASC
```

Comment: Perfect!  This worked.  Not sur why it is working on the live server, but will update that in case anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Hope its helped.